# Change lines in file only if they match the patterns in another file

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

Say I have these two files:

**inp**

```
11 hello
22 wonderful
33 beach
44 today
55 is
66 great
```

**pats**

```
11
44
55
```

I want to do something in inp, but only for lines that are in pats. E.g. say I want to append + at the end. I'd like the end result to be

**out**

```
11 hello+
22 wonderful
33 beach
44 today+
55 is+
66 great
```

Is there an easy way to do this with sed, awk or such? By easy I'd like not to have to write a (e.g. python) program, I'm more looking for something such as `grep -f pats inp` + `sed 's/$/+/'` together.

**Edit:**

I'd like it to work with pattern found anywhere in the line, e.g.:

**inp**

```
11 hello
wonderful22
beach 33 front
to44day
is55
gr 66 eat
```

**pats**

```
11
44
55
```

**out**

```
11 hello+
wonderful22
beach 33 front
to44day+
is55+
gr 66 eat
```

Answer (score 2):

```
awk 'NR==FNR {pats[$1]++; next} $1 in pats {$2=$2"+"} 1' pats inp
11 hello+
22 wonderful
33 beach
44 today+
55 is+
66 great
```

To check for a match anywhere in each line of `inp`, you could use an essentially similar approach, but extracting the portion to compare using `match`

```
awk 'NR==FNR {pats[$1]++; next} match($0,/[0-9]+/) && substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) in pats {$0=$0"+"} 1' pats inp2
11 hello+
wonderful22
beach 33 front
to44day+
is55+
gr 66 eat
```

(If you want to match against *arbitrary* patterns from the `pats` file, then a different approach would be required e.g. looping over the elements of the `pats` array explicitly.)

Comment: Thanks, nice idea, +1 - would this work for search instead of match by position? I.e. say numbers are not always in the first column, but can be anywhere?

Comment: @levantpied the same general method can likely be applied in that case - the specifics would depend on what exactly you mean by "anywhere"

Comment: Thanks - what I meant by anywhere is basically a string search instead of using `$1`. Or to put it another way, I want matching similar to `awk '/pat1|pat2|...|patN/'`.

Comment: @levantpied sorry, that's still unclear to me - the best thing IMHO would be to edit your question to include examples - or post a new question if you have a significantly different requirement.

Comment: Edited the question with another example.

Comment: @levantpied see updated answer

Comment: Thanks - yeah, I meant "arbitrary patterns". I just put numbers to be easier to describe "what I want to find" vs. "anything else on the line". As I said, I want it to work like `grep -f pats`, actually, `fgrep -f pats` - string, not regex match, but you get the point.

Answer (score 2):

bash syntax:

```
sed -f <(printf 's/^%d\>.*/&+/\n' $(<pats)) inp
```

The part inside `<()` part prints out a sed program to transform the appropriate lines:

```
$ printf 's/^%d\>.*/&+/\n' $(<pats)
s/^11\>.*/&+/
s/^44\>.*/&+/
s/^55\>.*/&+/
```

The `<()` syntax is bash process substitution, so you can take the output of a command and work with it like it comes from a file.
Then we have `sed -f sed_program inp` to actually transform the file

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
awk 'NR==FNR{Arr[$0];next}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)for(j in Arr)if(match($i,j)){F=1;$0=$0"+"}else{F=0}}1' pat.txt input.txt
    11 hello+
    wonderful22
    beach 33 front
    to44day+
    is55+
    gr 66 eat
```